# How to make continuous testing auto jump to failing test?

Tags: c#, resharper

Using Visual Studio 2017 and R# 2017.1 EAP 3

So I'm a keyboard junky and don't want to touch my mouse unless I have to.

When using continuous testing in resharper, I'm in my editor window, and am creating/editing unit tests or code and a test fails, however I can't see the failure details in thedetails pain of the failed test, I want it to auto select the test on failure.  painfully ( via keyboard ) I can go to the Continuous test window, move down to the failing test, move back to the editor window.

I'd be even happy if there's a short cut to make the Test window jump to first failing test / next failing test without having to leave the editor window if possible.